# How to handle JSP in SparkJava

Tags: jsp, spark-java

I'm trying to use Spark framework for my simple project.

I want to dispatch to a JSP on a request like

```
Spark.externalStaticFileLocation("/home/resources");
get("/home", (req, res) -> {
    return new ModelAndView("", "test.jsp");
});
```

Should I need to add any Template Engine to support JSP?